# Knapsack Problem with Multiple Properties

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

### Problem Description

I have many examples (say $N$) to choose from to train my machine learning model. However, I could only select $n \ll N$ based on a set of $K$ attributes $\{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_k\}$ already measured for the dataset.

Now I would like to find these $n$ samples so that the sum of the $K$ columns is maximized while the weights are as uniform as possible.

### What I Tried

This looks like a knapsack problem but with multiple attributes. However, direct Google search does not seem to give me a lot of relevant results as I am looking for an existing software package that could solve this problem (or perhaps its relaxed version).

### Numerical Example

Suppose I would like to select $n=3$ samples from a dataset of $N=5$ samples and $K=4$ attributes.

```
     A    B    C    D
0  0.7  0.4  0.8  0.5
1  0.7  1.0  0.3  0.7
2  0.8  0.5  0.4  0.8
3  0.8  0.3  0.6  0.5
4  0.2  0.8  0.6  0.2
```

which is generated with the code below:

```
import string
import itertools

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)

N = 5
n = 3
K = 4

measures = np.linspace(0.1, 1, 10)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.choice(measures, size=(N, K)),
    columns=list(string.ascii_uppercase)[:K],
)
```

By enumerating all cases, I obtain a table that looks like following:

|  | choice | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | (0, 1, 2) | 2.2 | 1.9 | 1.5 | 2 |
| 1 | (0, 1, 3) | 2.2 | 1.7 | 1.7 | 1.7 |
| 2 | (0, 1, 4) | 1.6 | 2.2 | 1.7 | 1.4 |
| 3 | (0, 2, 3) | 2.3 | 1.2 | 1.8 | 1.8 |
| 4 | (0, 2, 4) | 1.7 | 1.7 | 1.8 | 1.5 |
| 5 | (0, 3, 4) | 1.7 | 1.5 | 2 | 1.2 |
| 6 | (1, 2, 3) | 2.3 | 1.8 | 1.3 | 2 |
| 7 | (1, 2, 4) | 1.7 | 2.3 | 1.3 | 1.7 |
| 8 | (1, 3, 4) | 1.7 | 2.1 | 1.5 | 1.4 |
| 9 | (2, 3, 4) | 1.8 | 1.6 | 1.6 | 1.5 |

Then I would like the selected samples to best trade off the two constraints:

- The sum of all $K$ columns are large enough.
- The entropy of weights is large enough: the more uniform the "weights", the better.

So by these considerations, according to the plot below, I should choose samples indexed 0, 1, 2 or 0, 2, 4.

[image]

Comment: What does it mean to maximize some measure of each column?  Maximin?  An explicit numerical example might help clarify what you want.

Comment: @RobPratt Thank you for your suggestion. I sorted my head a little bit and I admit I was not specific enough. I added the "Numerical Example" section for your reference.

Comment: You can formulate this problem as MILP

Comment: It sounds like you have one constraint and two objectives and you want to find the Pareto frontier.

Comment: @RobPratt Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Crossposted to OR.SE: [Knapsack Problem with Multiple Properties](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/10614/491)

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_i$ the indicator of choosing the sample $i$, $a_{i,k}$ the measure of the sample $i$ for the attribute $k$. Isn't your problem equivalent to:

$$\min \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{K} a_{i, k}\left(1-\log\left(a_{i,k}\right)\right)\right)x_i : \sum_{i=1}^N x_i = n$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This looks right to me. Can you also provide a numerical simulation that solves my toy example (I do not know much about numerical optimization software though I do have Gurobi installed)?

Comment: You can use Gurobi to solve it directly.

Comment: You also need to consider the other objective of maximizing the sum.